# What went wrong with my launchd plist?

Tags: launchd, plist

I set up a launchd plist to run a shell script every morning at 8 AM

(see [Is there an easy way to automatically schedule a move of files matching a certain pattern from a user directory to a USB drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/459555/331833) for context).

Yesterday, I created the plist, put it in /Library/LaunchDaemons, and did a did a `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/sweep.plist` (either sudo'd or in a sudo bash) once it was in place.

***BUT IT DIDN'T WORK!*** It's called "sweep.plist," and it is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>sweep</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Users/europa/sweep.sh</string>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
<key>Hour</key>
<integer>8</integer>
<key>Minute</key>
<integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm absolutely certain that after I did the `launchctl load` yesterday, "sweep" showed up in a `launchctl list`, but my shell script didn't execute, and the daemon no longer shows up when I do a `launchctl list`.

***New:*** I checked the system log, and sure enough, there was an error message. Not sure what to do about it:
`May 10 08:00:05 Europas-Mac-mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (sweep[1299]): Program specified by service is not a Mach-O executable file.`

Looking at the shell script with a `ls -l`, it shows permissions as `-rwxr-xr-x@`

Any idea what I could have done wrong, or where to look for the problem?

Comment: I believe the calendar intervals need to be in an array.   See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) for more details.

Comment: Really? Then why would it say  "Program . . . is not a Mach-0 executable file"?

Comment: Dd you test out your script to ensure it works?

Comment: Ran it from a SUDO BASH'd command line before I'd even *attempted* to make it run on a schedule. Before I'd even settled on launchd to schedule it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062525/3654526

It seems that a generic shebang (`#!`) is fine if you're calling the script from a command line, but not from launchd. It needs to specify a shell in the shebang, i.e., `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: A "generic shebang" is not valid. Some things (like bash) may ignore it, but it's not something you should ever actually use. The purpose of a shebang line is to specify the interpreter to use on the file, and `#!` does not do that.

Comment: Point taken. Although I'd always understood that it identifies the file as a shell script, albeit without, as you point out, saying anything about what shell to use. And launchd wouldn't already be in a shell, so . . . .

Comment: It doesn't identify it as a *shell* script, but as a script of some kind -- could be shell, perl (`#!/usr/bin/perl`), awk (`#!/usr/bin/awk -f`), expect (`#!/usr/bin/expect`), etc. Some things (like bash) will assume it's a shell script, but they'll generally do the same thing if it doesn't have a shebang at all.